# Easy: Why does `network` command keep looking for an old router?

Tags: ip, dhcp

What am I missing in this manual dhcp configuration?

I'm using CentOS 6. From [Redhat's](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html) page I've setup a manual configured dhcp client:

> The **/etc/sysconfig/network** file should contain the following line:
>
> ```
> NETWORKING=yes
> ```
>
> The NETWORKING variable must be set to yes if you want networking to
>   start at boot time.
>
> The **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0** file should contain the
>   following lines:
>
> ```
> DEVICE=eth0 
> BOOTPROTO=dhcp 
> ONBOOT=yes
> ```

And from [another site's](http://blog.roozbehk.com/post/35156862882/redhat-add-network-eth) blog on the same:

> Append/modify configuration [/etc/sysconfig//network] as follows:
>
> ```
> NETWORKING=yes
> HOSTNAME=myserver.example.com
> GATEWAY=10.1.1.1
> ```

I've deleted the Linux file **/etc/recolv.conf** which was auto-generated with my old Belkin router's gateway preference, then issued the command:

```
# /etc/init.d/network restart
```

I also installed the `dhclient` package and issued the revoke command and request for new dynamic ip as described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-renew-dhcp-client-ip-address/).

I know these settings work because I used the same instructions to successfully connect to my old Belkin router (192.168.2.1). I've disconnected this router, deleted the resolv.conf file and connected to this other router (10.10.10.1). But when I issue the network restart command the Cent system is still looking for this old gateway. Why?

Could there be something left over from my last successful connection that I have not deleted? Or maybe a preference from NetworkManager--which I turned off using these [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_OpenStack/3/html/Installation_and_Configuration_Guide/Disabling_Network_Manager.html) instructions?

Comment: What do you mean by "is still looking for this old gateway"? What precisely are you seeing that make you think it's looking for the old gateway?

Comment: [network restart output](http://pastebin.com/wRu67S4S); the gateway address for the Belkin router is 192.168.2.1

Comment: Run `/etc/init.d/network stop ; ( ifconfig eth0 ; netstat -rn ) > /tmp/config ; /etc/init.d/network start ; ( ifconfig eth0 ; netstat -rn ) >> /tmp/config` to find out what the script actually changes. Paste the contents of `/tmp/config` into the question (we'll edit later to remove unnecessary stuff).